# Show $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^ix^{2^i}}{1+x^{2^i}} = \frac x {1-x}$ for $|x|<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Show $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^ix^{2^i}}{1+x^{2^i}} = \frac x {1-x}$ for $|x|<1$

We have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^ix^{2^i}}{1+x^{2^i}} = 
\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^ix^{2^i} \frac{1}{1+x^{2^i}} =
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^\infty (-1)^l 2^i x^{{2^i}(2l+1)}$

But in general I have no idea how to continue, for example the only way I know to put $2^i$ back into a term would be $\frac 1 {1-2x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (2x)^i$ but the indices don't seem to fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $|x| < 1$, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{2^i x^{2^i}}{1 + x^{2^i}} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^i \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1} x^{j 2^i}$$
For any positive integer $n$, $x^n$ appears on the right side as $x^{j 2^i}$ 
if $2^i | n$ and $j = n/2^i$.  Thus if $n = 2^k m$ with $m$ odd, 
the terms in $x^n$ are 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^k 2^i (-1)^{2^{k-i} m-1} x^{n} = (2^k - 2^{k-1} - \ldots - 1) x^n = x^n$$
As long as $|x| < 1$, absolute convergence lets you rearrange the series.
And finally,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Put $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{2^jx^{2^j}}{1+x^{2^j}}$ and $g(x==\frac{x}{1-x}$. It is easy to see that $\displaystyle 2f(x^2)=f(x)-\frac{x}{1+x}$, and that $\displaystyle 2g(x^2)=g(x)-\frac{x}{1+x}$. Put $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Then we have $h(0)=0$ and $2h(x^2)=h(x)$. Suppose that $h$ is not $0$. If you put $h(x)=\sum_{k\geq m} a_k x^k$, with $a_m\not =0$, $m\geq 1$, we get from the relation that $a_m=0$. Hence $h=0$ and we are done.